# Send Alexa a command from another device?

Tags: raspberry-pi, alexa, nodejs

I'm in the process of creating a Raspberry Pi-powered home automation system. I have a complicated node.js script running on the Pi, and I want to be able to send commands from the Pi to my Alexa (e.g. turn on lights, say something, etc). I've looked into AVS (Amazon Voice Service) but I'd have to convert text to an audio command for that, and I was wondering if there's a simpler way. Does anybody have experience in this type of thing?

Comment: please ask a question about the problem, not about people's experience

Comment: There is no (public) API to do that. The User Interface for Alexa is voice.

Comment: It might be easier to keep Alexa out of the loop when controlling devices in your home. As you have hit the wall everyone eventually does. Can you think of 1 thing Alexa can do that does not start w/a verbal command? I can't. So consider controlling the devices directly from your Raspberry Pi instead. There are likely web portals you can access to control your IOT devices. Or, there is the TASMOTA software effort where TASMOTA is burnt into you TASMOTA compatible IOT devices.  Now you can use MOSQUITO on your Raspberry Pi and send MQTT messages to control your IOT devices.

Comment: Can this be of help https://github.com/thorsten-gehrig/alexa-remote-control

Comment: @MatsK That looks promising, I'll have to look into it. You might want to consider expanding that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer lies in going the IFTTT route to control your device.
You can then control it from Alexa as well as other sources of control such as your javascript file.
Here are some Alexa IFTTT integrations to get you started.
https://ifttt.com/amazon_alexa

Comment: Will I be able to have it say something through IFTTT?

Comment: These guys say it works. Feel free to monkey around with it and let us know !  https://ifttt.com/voicemonkey